# How can I get a jQuery Mobile to work on desktop?

Tags: jquery, html

If you go to jquery mobile you would see that the site has code to implement mobile tools, but the tools also work on their desktop version so I wonder how they did that.

The link is here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/switch/

I tried to implement on of the codes on the site and I have no luck.

```
In the header:
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>


In the body:    
<div class="containing-element">
        <label for="flip-min">Flip switch:</label>
        <select name="flip-min" id="flip-min" data-role="slider">
            <option value="off">Switch Off</option>
            <option value="on">Switch On</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

How come this results in something different?
This returns something that looks like this:
[image]

Comment: first, you're including jQuery twice. Next, you're not including a page in your application. jQuery Mobile was written to support both mobile and desktop environments.

Comment: Not sure what you mean "not including a page in your application?

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/about/getting-started.html

Comment: Thank you!! Figured that out!

Answer (score 3):

i believe that this is probably because you are not linking the Jquery mobile stylesheet that comes with the library. It is the css styles that come with it that make many of the ui elements look the way that you see them on their website.

include this in your head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
```

and add this to your main wrapper div

```
<div data-role="page">
```

Comment: Thank you, also needed the <div data-role="page">

Comment: ah yes sorry i missed that.. EDITED to have the correct answer

Comment: Is there a way to style this page? It's overwriting any styles with something that just looks like a mobile page.

Comment: im sorry im not sure what you mean? are you saying that the default jquerymobile styles are overriding anything you try to apply?

Comment: Yeah, if you see here, it just covers my actual page.  Check the right hand side.  http://i.imgur.com/2mX1ssf.jpg

Comment: any element you put on the page that you do not give a specific jquery mobile class selector will show as the default html element which you can style appropriately. You can also override styling done by jquery by applying a custom class to the desired element. As long as you put your class after their class it will override whatever styles it was inheriting. for example <div class="jquerymobile class YourCustomClass"></div>

Comment: also make sure to load your custom stylesheet in your head AFTER you load the jquerymobile stylesheet